# Spring Data JPA with PageRequest and Predicate failing

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Im using Spring data Jpa specification and I would like to obtain non repetead registries, so I use distinct in query like that.

```
public static Specification<Actividad> criteriosConsultaGruposHandling(final String cif, final String razonSocial, final String nombreComercial, final List<Long> idsHandling) {

    Specification<Actividad> spec = new Specification<Actividad>() {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Actividad> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

            query.distinct(true);

            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
            if(cif != null && !cif.equals("")){
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.upper(root.join(Actividad_.empresa).get(Empresa_.cif)), "%" + cif.toUpperCase() + "%" ));
            }
            if(razonSocial != null && !razonSocial.equals("")){
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.upper(root.join(Actividad_.empresa).get(Empresa_.razonsocial)), "%" + razonSocial.toUpperCase() + "%" ));
            }
            if(nombreComercial != null && !nombreComercial.equals("")){
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.upper(root.join(Actividad_.empresa).get(Empresa_.nombrecomercial)), "%" + nombreComercial.toUpperCase() + "%" ));
            }
            if(idsHandling != null && !idsHandling.isEmpty()){
                Predicate pred = cb.conjunction();
                pred.getExpressions().add(root.join(Actividad_.grupohandlingactividads).get(Grupohandlingactividad_.grupohandling).get(Grupohandling_.idsubgrupo).in(idsHandling));
                predicates.add(pred);                   
            }

            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        }
    };

    return spec;
}
```

}

but when I do the findAll with the specification and pagerequest the page resulting from query is bad

```
Specification<Actividad> specificationActividad = ActividadSpecifications.criteriosConsultaGruposHandling(actividadForm.getEmpresa().getCif(), 
            actividadForm.getEmpresa().getRazonsocial(), actividadForm.getEmpresa().getNombrecomercial(),listaGruposAsignados);
    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(actividadForm.getPagina() -1, actividadForm.getMaxRegistros(), actividadForm.getOrder());
    Page<Actividad> resultados = actividadRepository.findAll(specificationActividad, pageRequest);
```

When I call findAll without pageRequest parameter I obtain rows without repetitions but when I call it with it don´t elimininate the repetitive rows.
Anyone could help me? Thanks in advance!